# Xcode 5 git merging data models - xcdatamodel

Tags: xcode, git

Am I missing something in Xcode, I am having trouble git merging data models in Xcode 5.

Xcode shows the content of the right xcdatamodel file, but unable to resolve any conflicts.

Have you experienced any issues in merging different xcdatamodel files?

Thanks in advance
Regards
Christian

Answer (score 0):

I solve this trouble. I just stop use this fu•¶g IDE. I use terminal git only for merge and other features.

Comment: Yes but a trouble hidded in Xcode merge tool. We merge xcdatamodel in manual mode with AppCode or terminal VimDiff. If Xcode try merge xcdatamodel it broked after that.

Comment: One could hope that Apple will give Xcode some loving as developers is part of there food chain. Happy coding.